# Data heavy application architecture performance

Tags: android, gmail

I’m curious as to how a data heavy app cache and prefetch data to make user experience seem less. Take gmail for example, if I install the app fresh and log in for the first time, the app always seem responsive.

I would assume the login has to be authenticated before data can be pulled. Is it 100% the animated activity transitions and the loading spinner or are there more going on under the hood?

Comment: This is an old video. However, I think this will give you a good start. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlkJzgjzL0c&t=413s

Answer (score 0):

Below is some techniques which you can use to make a better UX:

1. Always retrieve data using asynchronous
2. Using placeholder for UI while waiting for data instead of showing a progress dialog
3. Using lazy loading to load needed data only, not all.